# RxJS - Transform "Object" Events to an "Array" containing all the Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, websocket, rxjs

**CONTEXT:**

I have a Websocket Endpoint. That WS streams a set of `messages`. Each `message` has a set of Data I want to access in order to feed a Visualisation.

**THE PROBLEM:**

The Visualisation accepts only `Arrays`. And the WS Endpoint only has objects. I want to transform the individual Objects, into an array of objects.

**CODE:**

```
  webSocketRequest.onopen = () => {
    webSocketRequest.send(JSON.stringify(firstMessage));
    webSocketRequest.onmessage = (streamEvent) => {

      return of(streamEvent).pipe(
        map(event => JSON.parse(event.data)),
        filter(message => message.type === 'RECORD'), // Here I filter only for the Object I want
        tap(rec => console.log(rec.data.value)) // This returns my desired individual objects
      ).subscribe();
    };
  };
```

From that point on, I have faced a wall. Can somebody, help me please? Besically, I want to transform all the object, into a array that contains all of them. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand that correctly, you want to maintain a list of message and append every new message coming via websockets to this list.

1. Staightforward approach: create the array in your consumer, and modify it in .subscribe() callback:

```
const messages = [];
of(streamEvent)
  .pipe(...your pipe here...)
  .subscribe(message => messages.push(message))
```

2. A bit more fancy - you can do this directly in your pipe, and the resulting observable will emit a changed array every time new message is appended:

```
of(streamEvent)
  .pipe(
    ...your pipe here...,
    scan((messages, msg) => [...messages, msg], []),
    startWith([])
  )
```

This allows you do pass this observable to different end consumers, and they will be able to consume the array as it's changing, without duplicating the logic

Comment: Thank you really much. I will do the dirty work, with the non-fancy way, then circle back to make it better. Many thanks!!